# Assign multiple aliases to a sub query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a sub query and I need to join it with itself.
It looks something like this :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    ( ..-the same sub query-.. ) SQ1,
    ( ..-the same sub query-.. ) SQ2,
    ( ..-the same sub query-.. ) SQ3
WHERE
    ..-some joins between SQ1, SQ2, SQ3-..
```

Is there anyway to resolve this issue of not writing the same query multiple times. (The original query is too long to post but essentially I need to do this)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not make a temporary table and use it in your query?

Comment: I don't have the permissions to create tables. And even if I have, creating a table is not a good idea just for a query.

Comment: Share your tables structure and desired output you want to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the WITH factoring clause, such as

```
with sq as
  (select ... from ... where)
select *
from sq sq1,
     sq sq2,
     sq sq3
where sq1.id = sq2.id
  and ...
```